# PhantomJS page scraping with multiple load data

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm trying to scrape with PhantomJS this page : http://www.avrilgau.com/fr/5-chaussures . 
The aim is to get the links of all products. 
The problem is that new data is loaded when I scroll down. Every time I scroll down 12 new items are added to document.querySelectorAll("#content > ul > li > div > div a.img") .

I found a form hidden in the HTML code. When I submited this form I succeded to get 61 elements on a total of 110.

How can I do to get the links of all products?

My code so far :

```
var system  = require("system");
var fs      = require("fs");
var path = 'productLinks.txt';
var url = "http://www.avrilgau.com/fr/5-chaussures";
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
 console.log(msg);
};

page.open(url, function (status) {

var content = page.evaluate(function()
 {
  var allUrl=[];

  var tempNodeArray =document.querySelectorAll("#content > ul > li > div > div a.img");

  for (var i = 0; i < tempNodeArray.length; i++) {
    allUrl.push((tempNodeArray[i]).href);
  };

  return allUrl.join("\n")+"\n";


 });

console.log(content);
fs.write(path, content, 'a');

phantom.exit();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 61 products in that category, the infinityscroll stops at 61 products for me when using the site as intended. Where do you get the number 110?

Comment: I found a form with document.querySelector(".showall") and then I submited the form (document.querySelector(".showall").submit()). After I did the infinite scroll and got 110 items :(

Comment: When you use the show all button, and load all products with scroll on the resulting page, the extra products are duplicates. There are only 61 unique products.